# How do I use HTML Template to display nested loops

Tags: html, perl, templates

I'm trying to set up nested loops using tmpl_loop but I have very little experience with the HTML::Template module.

The layout I am trying to do is something like this:

```
Name       Start         End 
Dog      04-02-1996    06-19-2011 

Breed:  Terrier       Sex: Male 
Color:  Brown         Eye Color: Green 
Weight: 10 Pounds     Attribute: bla bla

Name       Start         End 
Dog      03-04-1985    06-01-1988

Breed:  Retriever     Sex: Female 
Color:  Black         Eye Color: Green 
Weight: 50 Pounds     Attribute: bla bla
```

And so on...

The number of dogs can vary and it may or may not have the additional information but when it does, all fields must be displayed.

This is the block I have which displays the horizontal information correctly.

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
    <tmpl_loop name=labels>
    <td class="label"> <TMPL_VAR label>: </td> 
    </tmpl_loop>
</tr>
<tmpl_loop name=values>
    <tr>
        <tmpl_loop name=values>
        <td><TMPL_VAR value ></td>
        </tmpl_loop>
    </tr>
</tmpl_loop>
</table>
```

But how do I modify the HTML template to display the information in the sample display?

Also, how would the corresponding Perl data structure look like?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you don't need nested loops.

Change your template file to:

```
<table>
    <TMPL_LOOP dogs>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td>Name</td>
            <td></td><td>Start</td>
            <td></td><td>End</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><TMPL_VAR ldogname></td><td><TMPL_VAR dogname></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lstart></td><td><TMPL_VAR start></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lend></td><td><TMPL_VAR end></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lbreed></td><td><TMPL_VAR breed></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lsex></td><td><TMPL_VAR sex></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lcolor></td><td><TMPL_VAR color></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><TMPL_VAR leye></td><td><TMPL_VAR eye></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lweight></td><td><TMPL_VAR weight></td>
            <td><TMPL_VAR lattr></td><td><TMPL_VAR attr></td>
        </tr>
    </TMPL_LOOP>
</table>
```

and your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::Template;

my $template=HTML::Template->new(filename=>'template.txt');
my @dogs=( #dogs data
    {dogname=>'Dog',start=>'04-02-1996',end=>'06-19-2011',breed=>'Terrier',sex=>'Male',color=>'Brown',eye=>'Green',weight=>'10 Pounds',attr=>'bla bla'},
    {dogname=>'Dog',start=>'03-04-1985',end=>'06-01-1988',breed=>'Retriever',sex=>'Female',color=>'Black',eye=>'Green',weight=>'50 Pounds',attr=>'bla bla'},
);
my %labels=(
    ldogname=>'',
    lstart=>'',
    lend=>'',
    lbreed=>'Breed: ',
    lsex=>'Sex: ',
    lcolor=>'Color: ',
    leye=>'Eye Color: ',
    lweight=>'Weight: ',
    lattr=>'Attribute: '
);
for my $dog (@dogs) { #mix labels and values
    while (my ($k,$v)=each %labels) {
        $dog->{$k}=$v;
    }
}
$template->param(dogs=>\@dogs);
print $template->output;
```

and you will have the desired output.

But to answer your question, you can check some examples of nested loops: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=770278 http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=193367 (google returns even more results)

Comment: This is very close to what I want. A couple things though.

My example was a bit off. I actually want the row heading (name, start, end) to be in each of the rows. So line 1 is heading, line 2 the values.

Another thing is each category header, should be in its own cell, ie breed, sex, etc..

So it'd be <td>Breed</td><td>Terrier</td>

Comment: I tried to reproduce your example! I'll update my answer to your new requirements, and you can figure it out by yourself after that if you need other changes in the HTML.

Comment: I tweaked the HTML a bit for formatting but this version does exactly what I need, so thank you! I will try to apply this in the exact way I plan to use this template with data retrieval from the DB. I hope I won't have any issues.

Comment: Ok so I fitted this into what I needed to do and I'm all done. Now in this version, I have all of the "secondary" fields, breed, color, sex, identified in the template. What if I didn't know what or how many secondary fields there are and wanted to loop through labels/values arrays? This is why I thought I'd need nested loops.

Comment: When you have nested loops, I believe you can't print the values of the outer loop inside the inner loop. So you should change the desired HTML output. For example you could have a 2xn table for each dog (pseudocode): `<TMPL_LOOP dogs><table><TMPL_LOOP labels><tr><TMPL_VAR labels></tr></TMPL_LOOP><tr><TMPL_VAR dogvalues></tr><table></TMPL_LOOP>`